# DashboardComponent.html:2981 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Am a simple progress bar in my dashboard, but whenever I run my angular 8 app, I end up with an error

```
DashboardComponent.html:2981 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

and the html doesn't load.

this is my DashboardComponent.ts file

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';@Component({
      selector: 'app-progress-bar',
       templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
    })
  
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() progress: number;
    @Input() total: number;
    color: string;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {

      //if we don't have progress, set it to 0.
      if(!this.progress) {
         this.progress = 0;
      }  //if we don't have a total aka no requirement, it's 100%.
      if(this.total === 0) {
         this.total = this.progress;
      } else if(!this.total) {
         this.total = 100;
      }  //if the progress is greater than the total, it's also 100%.
      if(this.progress > this.total) {
         this.progress = 100;
         this.total = 100;
      }  this.progress = (this.progress / this.total) * 100;  if(this.progress < 55) {
         this.color = 'red';  } else if(this.progress < 75) {
         this.color= 'yellow';  } else {
        this.color = 'green';
      } }
    }
```

how I am calling it from the dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-11">
            <h1 class="card-title"><span class="lstick"></span>Survey Progress</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-12">
            <div class="card card-hover" style="width: 100%;">
              <div class="box bg-dark text-center"
                   style="min-width: 100%;min-height: 300px;color: white;">
                <br><br>

                <app-progress-bar [progress]="10" [total]="100"></app-progress-bar>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

am not sure what am not doing right, and the progress bar is not being shown

Answer (score 0):

**At first сheck for endless cycle or recursion. Check warnings for circular dependency Check correctness of imports. U may added your component to imports in your ngModule instead of declaration. Any away U undo your recent actions to prevent error.**

Comment: hi @Syimyk is this the correct way of adding the app-progress-bar `<app-progress-bar [progress]="10" [total]="100"></app-progress-bar>` inside the div? or should be inside index.html?

Comment: Your problem is that inserted dashboard.component inside own template
`<app-progress-bar [progress]="10" [total]="100"></app-progress-bar>`
is inside 

`@Component({
      selector: 'app-progress-bar',
       templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
    })`

Comment: Hi @Syimyk how should I have it?

Comment: Remove `<app-progress-bar [progress]="10" [total]="100"></app-progress-bar>` inside
< app-progress-bar>

Comment: biut the progress bar wont show when I remove it?